# Bigcommerce legacy API validation javascript example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, authorization, bigcommerce

I need to validate Bigcommerce legacy API credentials using AJAX (more precisely, using $http in AngularJS)

Every time I post a request to a store api, I always get the response:
[{"status":401,"message":"No credentials were supplied in the request."}]

I've tried every combination of parameters and headers that I can think of, and still I get the same error message. I could not find a single example of javascript code to validate the old Bigcommerce API credentials (legacy API).

Please help!

Bigcommerce clients provide the following data:
username, api_path, api_token

Here is my code:

```
var encoded_access_token = window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(
    $scope.merchant.username + ':' + $scope.merchant.api_token
)));

$scope.merchant.api_path = 'https://store-ji3ql.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/time';

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: $scope.merchant.api_path,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded_access_token
    },
    isArray: false
}).success(function(returnData) {
    console.log('success!');
    console.log(returnData);
}).error(function(returnData) {
    console.log('error!');
    console.log(returnData);
});
```

Comment: Angular is actually forcing the GET request to be an OPTIONS request due the request being cross-domain.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you could not validate Bigcommerce legacy API credentials with JS but a backend language such PHP, Ruby, ...

You could employ BC's APIs on you own server with PHP then expose it for JS code to call from.

(I have not implemented on my own, but that's what I heard from a bigcommerce developer)

Please visit this for more information: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/clients